# List not showing in html

Tags: python, html, django, list

Im trying to create a table in html but the list is not even working

This is my site.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1>tab in my website</h1>
<p>site info</p>

{% if result_dict %}
<ul>
{% for i in result_dict %}
    <li> {{ forloop.counter }} - {{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>This is not working</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

This what what i have in my views.py

```
def prtg(request, *args, **kwargs):
response = requests.get("https://prtg.c3ntro.com/api/table.json?content=status=down&username=someuser&passhash=somehash&count=200000000")
data = response.json()
d = data
result_list = [d for d in data['status%3Ddown'] if d['status'] == 'Down']
return render(request, 'blog/prtg.html', {'title':'PRTG'}, {'result_list': result_list})
```

When I open the page is not loading any information and well it's supposed to show at least the sensors that I'm filtering but nothing shows us, instead I get the message of the else statement "This is not working"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way to show what I wanted in html

So the answer was very simple altho I havent found a way to auto refresh this

But the code goes likes this

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
def example_page(request):
    context = {"title" : "example"}
    url = "my.website.json"
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()
    d = data
    result_list = [d for d in data['status%3Ddown'] if d['status'] == 'Down']
    df = pd.DataFrame(result_list)
    return HttpResponse(df.to_html())
```

That way we get a dataframe built-in html

Altho you must refresh the page to get new data from the json url, got it working tho thanks for your time, ill leave my answer if anyone is having trouble with this

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. The items need to be in the same dictionary:

```
return render(request, 'blog/prtg.html', {'title':'PRTG', 'result_list': result_list})
```

and, you've called it `result_list`, not `result_dict`, so use that name in the template.

```
{% if result_list %}
<ul>
{% for i in result_list %}
    <li> {{ forloop.counter }} - {{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p>This is not working</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hey Daniel thanks for the answer, I changed it and it's still not showing up the information :( , I tried doing the request via CLI using a loop to pop up the information and it's showing up every 2 seconds, why it wont show up in the django platform??